# System.OutOfMemoryException [BITMAP]

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с очень странной багой при работе с битмапами.

Цель - вырезать кусок изображения. С pictureBox`а или напрямую изображения - не важно.

Рассмотрим 2 примера с изображением напрямую.

Первый:

```
 Bitmap from = new Bitmap(imagePath);
 Bitmap to   = from.Clone(new Rectangle(200, 200, 650, 800), from.PixelFormat);
```

Второй:

```
Bitmap from = new Bitmap(imagePath);
Bitmap to   = from.Clone(new Rectangle(20, 20, 650, 800), from.PixelFormat);
```

Выполняем второй пример - все отлично работает (хотя размер вырезанного изображения больше вырезанного изображения из первого примера).

А вот при первом примере получаю ошибку:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: "Недостаточно памяти."

Отсюда вопрос, почему так происходит? Прямоугольник точно в изображении находится, то есть за рамки не выходит. С ресурсами железа тоже вроде все хорошо.

Comment: _"хотя размер вырезанного изображения больше вырезанного изображения из первого примера"_ - вроде в обоих случаях вырезается размер 650х800?

Comment: @Regent опа, походу тут я просчитался. Почему-то думал, что вторые 2 координаты - правый нижний угол... Аж стыдно стало:)

Comment: Лично у меня большой вопрос вызывает: почему при некорректном прямоугольнике решено было кидать `OutOfMemoryException`. Выглядит очень странным решением... Кидался бы Exception с подходящим названием и описанием ошибки - было бы сразу понятно что не так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе [`Rectangle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Rectangle__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
public Rectangle (int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Третий и четвертый аргументы это не координаты правого нижнего угла, а ширина и высота прямоугольника.

Предполагаю, что в первом случае прямоугольник выходит за рамки исходного изображения.

Comment: Да, верно. Не углядел что-то:( Спасибо!

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Бывает :) Пожалуйста!